# R skips lines from /dev/stdin

Tags: r, terminal

I have a file with a list of numbers (make it for yourself: `for x in $(seq 10000); do echo $x; done > file`).

```
$> R -q -e "x <- read.csv('file', header=F); summary(x);"

> x <- read.csv('file', header=F); summary(x);
       V1       
 Min.   :    1  
 1st Qu.: 2501  
 Median : 5000  
 Mean   : 5000  
 3rd Qu.: 7500  
 Max.   :10000
```

Now, one might expect `cat`ing the file and reading from `/dev/stdin` to have the same output, but it does not:

```
$> cat file | R -q -e "x <- read.csv('/dev/stdin', header=F); summary(x);"
> x <- read.csv('/dev/stdin', header=F); summary(x);
       V1       
 Min.   :    1  
 1st Qu.: 3281  
 Median : 5520  
 Mean   : 5520  
 3rd Qu.: 7760  
 Max.   :10000
```

Using `table(x)` shows that a bunch of lines were skipped:

```
    1  1042  1043  1044  1045  1046  1047  1048  1049  1050  1051  1052  1053 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
 1054  1055  1056  1057  1058  1059  1060  1061  1062  1063  1064  1065  1066 
    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 ...
```

It looks like R is doing something funny with `stdin`, as this Python will properly print all the lines in the file:

```
cat file | python -c 'with open("/dev/stdin") as f: print f.read()'
```

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568968/r-programming-read-csv-skips-lines-unexpectedly) seems related, but it is more about skipping lines in a malformed CSV file, whereas my input is just a list of numbers.

Comment: The problem disappears if you use `stdin` instead of `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd that's interesting indeed! Any idea why, and which OS were you using? (linux, unix, darwin, cygwin)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I do not know why it happens. I first thought that the input was buffered and that only the first buffer was read, but if I increase the size of the file, more data is read. Since `stdin` is recognized by R, it may interfering in some way with `/dev/stdin` and silently stealing some of the lines. I am on Linux.

Comment: I'm on Linux as well. And using plain old `stdin` is the fix (I'm new to R and didn't know it supported that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head --bytes=4K file | tail -n 3`

yields this:

```
1039
1040
104
```

This suggests that R creates an input buffer on /dev/stdin, of size 4KB, and fills it during initialisation. When your R code then reads /dev/stdin, it starts in file at this point:

```
   1
1042
1043
...
```

Indeed, if in file you replace the line `1041` by `1043`, you get a "3" instead of "1" in the `table(x)`:

```
3  1042  1043  1044  1045  1046  1047  1048  1049  1050  1051  1052  1053 
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
...
```

The first `1` in `table(x)` is actually the last digit of `1041`. The first 4KB of file have been eaten.