# Is there an fread analog for reading from stdin?

Tags: linux, r, pipe, data.table

I'd like to use `fread` in a (R)script that would get input data via the linux pipe mechanism. Is there an `fread` analog for the following?

```
read.csv(file = 'stdin', ...)
```

I'll also settle for reading `stdin` some other way and then using `fread` to parse it, as I mainly want this for `fread`'s superior separator and header logic.

Comment: My understanding is that `fread` memory-maps the file, and I wouldn't think you can memory-map stdin... so my guess is "no, there isn't".

Comment: @Thomas smth like this `cat file | myscript.r`; and then read the `stdin` pipe from the script

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why the down-votes? Probably someone should explain...??

Comment: @eddi, in that case, why not `Rscript myscript.r file` and use `commandArgs` inside the script?

Comment: @Arun because most of the time I actually do `head file | myscript.r` or `zcat file | myscript.r`

Comment: @eddi, looking at `fread` it seems not possible (at least not obvious to me).

Comment: @eddi, if you want to salvage this question, probably you should add some details about what you mean. I still am not getting the reason for the down-votes pouring in though.

Comment: @Arun it's because I disagreed with meta people http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186877/what-exactly-is-wrong-with-this-title

Comment: @eddi You've been around long enough to know what a reproducible example looks like.

Comment: @GSee, I agree with the idea, but I fail to see how this question could be made reproducible. He doesn't know how/if `fread` can be used in that manner.. What example are you asking for? An example of how it's with `read.csv`?

Comment: @Arun, for starters, there's no data!

Comment: @GSee I've already figured out the answer, but I really don't see what reproducible code you'd want for this? A script that just has `fread('stdin')` in it or `read.csv(file='stdin')`??

Comment: @eddi, DWin managed to create a reproducible example in his answer.  Perhaps you could study that.

Comment: @GSee sorry I don't get it, I don't understand what code would create a reproducible example of the above, except for creating an R file and running Rscript

Comment: @eddi, after you enter `read.csv('stdin')`, then what do you do?

Comment: @Thomas, you should read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16499642/559784).

Comment: @GSee - it doesn't matter, but in this case, I actually literally do nothing - I just want to use `fread` to output text better in a console

Comment: You don't need `fread`, `read.csv`, or anything else to do _nothing_.

Comment: @GSee I don't think you get it - I use R to display text better than `cat` would

Comment: @eddi you've shown no such better display of text in your Question.

Comment: @Thomas, my understanding was that you *dint know* what `stdin` argument for `read.csv` was supposed to do. So I linked to the first question I found (with a simple google search). My understanding is that it had nothing to do with `tagging` at the time you asked the question.

Comment: @GSee because that's not the question, the question is self-contained - reading `stdin` using `fread`

Comment: how I use that readout afterwards is irrelevant to the question

Comment: @Thomas, and I don't think it's linux specific. On windows, I think it's `read.csv(stdin())`.. Not sure though. Hadn't used in a while.

Comment: it deserves also a `csv` tag.

Comment: @Metrics no it doesn't, this is a generic read issue and has very little to do with `csv`

Comment: @Thomas, it doesn't make sense to add `zcat`and `csv` to this question as it's not relevant to this question at all!!! It was just an usage example!

Comment: @Thomas that was added just as an example and is not relevant to the question, the question is about reading a file, not zcat'ing

Comment: @Thomas, read the question title. It'll be obvious what the question is actually about. You need not add every little example as a tag.

Comment: @eddi, you certainly manage to stir things up whether it be asking question or answering, here on SO or there on meta.. :)

Comment: @eddi: Thanks. It appears to be the problem with reading the csv file (as the title says)

Comment: @Metrics, no it's a problem of reading a file in a way similar to how `read.csv` does (which is just an example from a larger family of file-reading functions); it doesn't have to be a csv file.

Comment: @Arun yeah; I'm actually slowly warming up to the idea of deleting this question and my answer - if SO community doesn't need what I consider to be a good question and answer, that's fine by me.

Comment: Thomas, I agree that's a better title, but then I had a very different one to begin with and that silly one wasn't chosen by me @RobertHarvey

Comment: @Thomas:Now the title makes sense!

Comment: I feel like people here are viewing this question under a microscope. Maybe just me...

Comment: @eddi: The way you keep people from putting silly titles on your question is to provide a decent title to begin with.

Comment: @Arun: The OP posted a question on Meta about this question.  He invited the scrutiny.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - you wanna ask the people on `r` whether the title I chose was a decent one or not? (I actually think Thomas's one is better, but that's not the question)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I agree with your title change. But not with the tag editing and the million edits regarding getting the perfect question that's going on at the moment. Have you seen how many edits this question has had?

Comment: Actually, I'm back for one more edit to try to make this reproducible for the benefit of future readers. Also, I'll +1 it now that I get what it's about.

Comment: @eddi: I think we made that perfectly clear on Meta.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes I am aware of the Meta question. I would attribute Thomas' "not understanding" the question to his apprehension. Although I agree with GSee's point on aspects to have improved the question. It certainly was not unclear (to me).

Comment: [this is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186897/meta-and-so-behavior-lowering-so-value) (surprisingly, as it shoudln't be) relevant to this question

Comment: @eddi How in the world is that relevant to this question?

Comment: @GSee in the same way as meta-related down-votes and edits are; it gives an idea of why this looks like a bad question

Comment: @Arun I'm not sure what "apprehension" means in that sentence, but I didn't understand it because it didn't make sense. It only made sense when eddi answered his own question, which let me reverse engineer the question.

Comment: @eddi, you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784373/process-substitution/15785789#15785789

Comment: @Thomas, the usage I was going for is "the act of understanding" or "notion or conception". Basically *you* did not understand it. The fact that Joshua commented (and DWin answered) within minutes after the post is a testimony to that, in my view. It could have been better but unclear wasn't one of the cases.

Comment: @flodel I'm a bit unclear on how to use that for `fread`, seems like what you suggested there is just an alias for `file='stdin'` in `read.*` no? (for the 'stdin' case, you have other cases covered there relevant to that question)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out it's as simple as:

```
fread('file:///dev/stdin')
```

This works, because `fread` actually creates a temporary file when the first 7 characters are "file://" or "http://" and uses `download.file` to copy the data there and then `fread` that.

---

**Update:** As of [version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=984) one can use shell commands in `fread`, making another solution possible:

```
fread('cat /dev/stdin')
```

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes on this answer, an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: + 1 because I learnt something new. Sometimes I simply don't get Stackoverflow,  still don't get why those downvotes, seriously.

Comment: Downvoting *this* is plain petty. Downvoting the Q is one thing, but the Answer. *sigh*. +1

Comment: download.file copies the data?!?!  Would want to avoid that certainly, especially if the data is "big".

`fread(' cat')` also works (note: the space is necessary for fread to consider it a system command)

Comment: This is super useful. How we could read several files? Like Rscript script.R File1 File2 File3 using this?

Comment: That's a different problem - simply parse the command line arguments and read the files.

Answer (score 3):

All of the `read.*` functions use 'scan' under their hoods. `scan` is fairly low level but does have the capacity for parsing lines of data into different classes.

```
> mat <- matrix(scan(), 4,4) # will paste in block of data 
1: 0.5 0.1428571 0.25
4: 0.5 0.1428571 0.25
7: 0.5 0.1428571 0.25
10: 0.5 0.1428571 0.25
13: 0.5 0.1428571 0.25
16: 0.5 
17:        # Terminate with two <cr>'s
Read 16 items
> mat
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.5000000 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.5000000
[2,] 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.1428571
[3,] 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.1428571 0.2500000
[4,] 0.5000000 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.5000000


> lst <- scan(what=list(double(0), "a"))
1: 4 t
2: 6 h
3:  8 l
4: 8 8
5: 
Read 4 records
> lst
[[1]]
[1] 4 6 8 8

[[2]]
[1] "t" "h" "l" "8"
```

You should also look at the `?connections` page.

Comment: thanks, `scan` is the first function I looked at, but I can't figure out how to combine it with `fread`