# R readLines from console- how to signal end of input

Tags: r

I want to use readLines function for input from console of variable number of lines and store it to a vector:

```
v <- readLines()
```

How do I signal the end of input? Control-c cancels the process and no 'v' object is formed. Control-Z stops R program altogether. Typing 'EOL' or 'EOF' do not work.

I tried following function but it gives error:

```
getinput = function(){
    v=""
    while(TRUE){
        line = readLines(n=1)
        if(line=="") break
        v = v+line
    }
    v
}

> getinput()
firstentry
Error in v + line : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>
```

I am using R on Debian Linux. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493669/how-to-read-input-from-the-terminal-using-dev-stdin-and-read-csv may help (that being said, CRTL D twice doesn't work for me through RStudio / RGui on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<CTRL-D>` will signal EOF. If you're using [ess](http://ess.r-forge.org), try `C-c C-c`. Hope that helps and good luck. Leave a comment if you need further assistance.

Comment: In Linux running native R, control-D works, but while running windows R package in Linux with wine, control-D does not work. Instead, control-Z works there.

Comment: In your question, you said "I am using R on Debian Linux", but thanks for the information.

Comment: I am using both native R (from Debian stable repository) and Windows R under wine in same Linux. This is because latest packages are not available in native R in Debian Stable. Your answer was very helpful. Thanks.