# R: lost entries after applying write.csv2

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a problem with `write.csv` function.
I have a DB in an external csv-file, which I load in R through `read.csv2` function. Then the script does some normalization, after it, I write the DB through `write.csv2`.
The number of entries is 24500.

Loading the normalized DB in an another script (again through `read.csv2`), it results to be just 23700 entries. In the same time, in Excel, I can see all the 24500 entries. **Re-saving it from Excel, and re-loading it in R through `read.csv2`, the result is correct (24500 entries).**

I suppose to make a mistake when I try to save the DB.

The sketch of the scripts:

```
#SCRIPT 1

DB <- read.csv2("DB.csv", header = TRUE, 
                na.strings = c("MISSING_VALUE", "", " ", "NA", "#DIV/0!"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #24577 entries

#normalization

write.csv2(DB, "DB.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE) #data.frame DB contains 24577 entries

#SCRIPT 2

DB <- read.csv2("DB.csv", na.strings = "NA", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #23787 entries
```

I've tried also `fwrite` function from `data.table` library, but the result is the same.

Thank you so much!

Comment: At a minimum you need to suppress the comment character handling with `comment.char=""` because of the values of "#DIV/0!" . The octothorpe is the default R "comment.char". I've explained this in more detail with additional tips on how to use `count.fields` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568968/r-programming-read-csv-skips-lines-unexpectedly

Comment: With count.fields my script is more corresctm thank you. Thank you so much for the link also! Now it works with `quote = ""`.

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer to keep it from lying in hte unanswered questions queue.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need to suppress the comment character handling with comment.char="" because of the values of "#DIV/0!" . The octothorpe is the default R "comment.char". I've explained this in more detail with additional tips on how to use count.fields at: [R Programming: read.csv() skips lines unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568968/)